# stomp extension for php in windows 7

Tags: php, windows, pecl, stomp

I am trying to install stomp extension for php5.5.12 version, i have wamp server2.5 and windows 7 64 bit pc. I have downloaded the dll file of stomp extension from pecl website [1]: http://pecl.php.net/package/stomp , and enables the entry for the same in php.ini file with the help of phpinfo(), now when i restart the wamp server and tried to see the stomp extension in phpinfo screen it is not there,and there is an warning message in php error file which says that: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_stomp.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`
I tried to searched different blogs and google,but could not find the running solution.can any one please help me.

Is there any url from where i can download the 64bit stomp dll file , i have tried the urls like

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/
that is not working

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the mismatch of the versions.I am using the `wamp` on `windows 64` bit but the dll file for `stomp` is 32 bit version that is why the error is there. But unfortunately there is no dll file of 64 bit version for windows and the official site http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ is also down, so alternatevly i got the `Stomp`,`Frame` etc. classes from the `drupal` `stomp` module and made a php file which will include these files ,it is working perfectly fine for me.